# jQuery Colorpicker add multiple color pallettes in one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker, spectrum

I am using **[Spectrum Colorpicker](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/)** and need to add multiple colorpicker pallettes in one div. By default it has to show only one colorbox, onclick of +add it has to add one more colorbox and so on...

Thanks in Advance for your help,

My HTML Code:

```
<!-- Color Picker -->
<div class="colorpicker-container">
    <input class="full" />
    <a href="#">+ Add</a>  
</div>
<!-- /Color Picker -->
```

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

HTML

```
 <!-- Color Picker -->
    <div class="colorpicker-container">
        <input class="full" />
        <a class="add" href="#">+ Add</a>  
    </div>
    <!-- /Color Picker -->
```

JQuery

```
  $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
           $(this).before("<input class='full' />"); 
            $('.full:empty').spectrum({
               showPaletteOnly: true, // if you want to only have the palette
               showPalette:true,
               palette: [ // here the colors you want to have on your palette
                 ['black', 'white', 'blanchedalmond',
                 ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'violet']
               ]
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi Twain, Thanks for quick reply... It has almost done my requirement.. but onclick +Add it has to popup colorpicker pallette instead of colorbox then clicking on it... your help highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: i updatet my answer, you can specify your spectrum like you want to in the click function :)

Comment: Again, thanks for your help @twain. Will try that as I am not much into programming :(

Comment: I've updatet it again to support you. For more options just look in the spectrum api at https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/ :)

Comment: Thanks @twain... I think this should do :)